# How hide collapse on vue-bootstrap on window resize?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to close `collapse` when resize the window.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.hideCollapse)
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.hideCollapse)
  },
  methods: {
    hideCollapse() {
    console.log('hide collapse')
       // what should I call to make the collapse hide
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1 variant="primary">Toggle Collapse</b-button>
  <b-collapse id="collapse-1" class="mt-2">
    <b-card>
      <p class="card-text">Collapse contents Here</p>
      <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1-inner size="sm">Toggle Inner Collapse</b-button>
      <b-collapse id="collapse-1-inner" class="mt-2">
        <b-card>Hello!</b-card>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-card>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a data property called `open` and bind it to `v-model` directive of `b-collapse` component then update inside the resize event callback :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.hideCollapse)
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.hideCollapse)
  },
  methods: {
    hideCollapse() {
      console.log('hise collapse')
      this.open=true
      
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<!-- App -->
<div id="app">
  <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1 variant="primary">Toggle Collapse</b-button>
  <b-collapse v-model="open" id="collapse-1" class="mt-2">
    <b-card>
      <p class="card-text">Collapse contents Here</p>
      <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1-inner size="sm">Toggle Inner Collapse</b-button>
      <b-collapse id="collapse-1-inner" class="mt-2">
        <b-card>Hello!</b-card>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-card>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
```

Comment: However your answer opens the collapse not closes, It just happens for one time because for next window resizing the value of `open` doesn't change so no changes happen. I prefer to `emit` to a bootstrap-vue event or ...

Comment: you could do `this.open=!this.open`

Comment: Not good recommendation, because at first the `open` should be true which made the collapse be open but at first I  need it be closed.